# C++: How can I make the code auto input random numbers?

Tags: c++

I was working on this simple code which, in sum, should keep asking you to input in a number that is different than the number of input attempts you went through, hence, it will start asking you not to input 0 and as long as you don't input 0, it will reiterate and ask you not to input 1.

I wanted, however, to modify the program in order for it to run itself attempting random inputs, just to see how long it would run before getting the right number.

Here is what I came up with, before getting stuck:

```
#include <iostream>

//i was told the following libraries give you random numbers
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numberAttempts = -2;
    int numberEntered = !(numberAttempts);

    int xRan;    // I was told this little bit should get you random numbers
    srand(time(0));

    xRan = rand() % 100 + 1; //arbitrary randomization rule

    while (!((numberAttempts+1)==numberEntered)){

        int counter = numberAttempts + 2;

        cout << "Please enter any number but " << counter
             << ".\n>>";

        numberEntered ==  //here is where i'd like to have a random input. 

        cout << "Number Entered: " << numberEntered
             << endl;
        numberAttempts++;

        }
    cout << "\n\nWhy the did you do that?\n\n\n\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Setting `numberEntered = xRan;` makes it identical to setting numberEntered to 0 at the first iteration: it responds but promptly closes.

I firmly believe It's just a matter of reassigning `numberEntered` but I wouldn't know how.

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: suggested rephrasing the first paragraph. Not conveying a clear meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple matter moving the assignment `rand() % 100 + 1` from `xRan` to `numberEntered` inside the while loop. You can actually do away entirely with the `xRan` variable. Your code with this implemented is shown below. However please note that because the random function will only return a value between 1-100 if the number of attempts gets above 100 without being matched to the `numberAttempts` then the loop will run forever and will eventually crash. To solve this issue I have put in another requisite in the while loop `!((numberAttempts+1)==numberEntered) && (numberAttempts < 100)`

```
#include <iostream>

//i was told the following libraries give you random numbers
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numberAttempts = -2;
    int numberEntered = !(numberAttempts);

    srand(time(0));

    while (!((numberAttempts+1)==numberEntered) && (numberAttempts < 100)){

        int counter = numberAttempts + 2;

        cout << "Please enter any number but " << counter
             << ".\n>>";

        numberEntered = rand() % 100 + 1;

        cout << "Number Entered: " << numberEntered
             << endl;
        numberAttempts++;

        }
    cout << "\n\nWhy the did you do that?\n\n\n\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** This code will **not** work every time.
*Below is a Working iteration*
[image: Working iteration]

Comment: Uhh i was so close...

It worked, thank you very much!

About the rand parameter: yes i was aware of the loop, i just put 100 for the sake of testing, but thank you for you input on that front too.

You can't believe how much fun i'm having seeing the code play catch 22 with itself!

Comment: @GuillermoMurúa No problem please read through my edit though as this code will not work every time. This is simply a probability thing and has nothing to do with the quality of the code.